# How to get any column entry from another table of database based on the entry taken in form?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am new to laravel and facing an issue. I have a database and there are two tables named groups and clients. I have a form and there are three fields: name, email and group. The group is dropdown select which is populated by groups entries from the database. Now while creating a new client, I want my clients table to have relation with groups table. It will work like this:

Will enter the name, email and will select the group it will associate with. The 'Client' table will get the id (There is a id column in the database, which is on auto_increament) of the 'Groups' table.

I have created one to one relation and when I put group_id manually in the database, it is showing the respective group. But I want the code to get the group_id while creating new entry.

Here is the code which is creating new entry:

```
Student::create([
        'name'              => request('name'),
        'email'             => request('email'),
        'group_id'          => request('group_name')// I want the group Id here,
        'user_id'           => auth()->user()->id
    ]);

    return back()->with('success', 'The registration is completed');
```

Here is the form:

```
@extends ('layouts.app')

        @section('main')

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="post" action="/student" class="">

                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Client Name:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Client Email:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="group_name">Select Group:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="group_name">
                        @foreach ($groups as $group)
                        <option>{{ $group->group_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>


        @endsection
```

Here is the error code:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'group_group_name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `students` (`name`, `email`, `group_id`, `user_id`) values (Nayan Chowdhury, nayan.1aacl@gmail.com, Marketing, 1))
```

Comment: You can make that field null by default in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong. Try

```
<select class="form-control" name="group_name">
    @foreach ($groups as $group)
    <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->group_name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped :)